# Can we schedule cron job in the php script?

Tags: php, cron, cron-task

I'm new to this cronjobs and I want few emails (2k to 3k mails to be more precise) to be sent at specific time and date which are in the database table.Currently to achieve this, I'm calling my mail function file(sendmail.php) for every minute using cron job and comparing the current time and the time which comes from the db table, if true the mail will be sent.By doing this I'm afraid there will be some effect on the performance.

Can we schedule cronjob right after the insert query in the php script. So that I can pass those time and date variables to it?

Does calling the file for every minute in the cron job is a good practice? Will the performance get effected because my application will be used by 25 users at a time?

Although by calling the file for every minute achieves my task, but still want to know if there are any better ways.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> for every minute using cron

If you're firing off cron jobs every minute then you're doing some thing wrong. There are problems with jitter, and concurrency.

> comparing the current time and the time which comes from the db table

Does that mean you are doing the tie check *outside* of the DBMS? That would be very silly.

> Can we schedule cronjob right after the insert query in the php script

Yes, although you'd need to use sudo to create privilege separation. However you having (potentially) thousands of cron jobs is a very bad idea.

While there is a *lot* missing from your problem statement, based on what you have said, I'd suggest having a cron job running once every (say) 15 minutes, polling the database for the emails to be sent in that time window  - with the time comparison and concurrency locking done in the database.

Comment: firstly, thank you for taking your time to answer.Actually there will be no more than 1-5 rows in the db table which only saves date,time and status(Active or Inactive).So I think I won't be having any problem using sudo way because we will be scheduling the cronjob exactly at the time which is in the db table.But the main problem is I'm nowhere able to find any source for sudo way to schedule the cronjob right in the php script.Please correct me if I have gone wrong somewhere and please direct me if you know any source regarding sudoway of writing cron.

Comment: Doing a **lot** of reading between the lines, it sounds like you are not trying to send emails on a schedule but rather at a specific delay - which implies cron is the wrong approach (unless you use a polling mechanism) rather you shjould be using atd.  "I'm nowhere able to find any source for sudo way to schedule the cronjob right in the php script" - this is the easiest part of all the things you are asking. By a very long way. Really. Brain numbingly simple. Nobody would publish it because it is so obvious.